# Return largest number in a group in MySQL

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have three MySQL tables that I use to keep track of uptimes internally.  I like to do some basic stats (mainly for queries to run into an eventual jpGraph) and since all uptimes are kept for historical purposes, rather than discarding, I like to show the maximum in certain instances.

I can't figure out a way to do so.

```
select * from stats
inner join servers
on stats.sid = servers.sid
inner join os
on servers.os = os.oid
order by uptime desc;
```

essentially, sid in stats can have non-unique server names since it is a foreign key for server_name in the servername table.  So, the largest number in uptime should be only returned if there are multiple server sid's being listed, obviously if there is only one, it should be printed as well.  I hope I explained this well enough.

```
sid uptime  sid os  server_name name    oid 
 7  47647995    7   3   weinraub.net    GNU/Linux Debian    3
 9  5474640 9   2   hera    Windows 7   2
 1  3498373 1   4   ares    Mac OS X Mountain Lion  4
 8  1024013 8   2   jweinraub-dt3   Windows 7   2
 8  946330  8   2   jweinraub-dt3   Windows 7   2
 8  687139  8   2   jweinraub-dt3   Windows 7   2
```

So, as you can see here, jweinraub-dt3 has three instances.  I only want the largest uptime for each server_name.

```
mysql> desc stats;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| zid         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| sid         | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| uptime      | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lastCheckin | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> desc servers;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| sid         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| server_name | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| os          | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> desc os;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| oid   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| logo  | mediumblob  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**added table schema**

Comment: you didnt explain well :) . you want one largest value only ?

Comment: maybe sample data and example output would help

Comment: Please explain if/why the following is not enough: `select max(uptime) from <your join> group by server_name`

Comment: can you post your servers and os tables also

Comment: I added the schemas in the original question since I don't think I can format text in a comment.,

Comment: @alexis - Perhaps I implemented it wrong, but it only returns the the maximum uptime of the entire data set rather than the maximum of each server.  So, it returned one row, rather than the four expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try finding the largest uptime for each sid.

```
 SELECT MAX(uptime) AS max_uptime,
        sid
   FROM stats
  GROUP BY sid
```

Then, join that virtual table to the other stuff.

```
SELECT whatever, whatever
  FROM (
         SELECT MAX(uptime) AS max_uptime,
                sid
           FROM stats
          GROUP BY sid
       ) AS s
  JOIN servers ON s.sid = servers.sid
  JOIN os ON servers.os AS os.oid
 ORDER BY max_uptime DESC
```

The trick here is to summarize (aggregate) the stats table before joining it to the other tables.

Pro tip: don't use SELECT * in software. Especially don't use it when you're trying to explain what you need in your result set.

Comment: I am still new to the idea of innerjoins and I couldn't figure out how to get the columns from multiple tables to match up the foreign keys to the primary keys of the other table.  So.. not its an excuse, but I did select * as a quick __hack__ to get results

Comment: maybe i messed up, but I am getting an error on the join os on servers... if i remove it, it executes, and from my original the os joined worked.  But this is a fantastic help and does what I needed, I just need to clean up the selections/joins.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
select     ..., max(uptime)

from       stats

... 

group by   sid
order by   max(uptime) desc
```